# How to do limited image recognition on a gauge?

Tags: image-processing, image-recognition

We have a physical gauge and we can not tamper it and the easiest way to do it would be using smartphone to take a picture of it and send it to server there it would process it and recognized what gauge is showing.

The images can be taken from different angles in various backgrounds yet the scale and the pointer are highly regulated so it will stay the same (color, shape, even font).

Is there SaaS that doe this if not is there a library that can be used for that?

Comment: I know I is a standard "where do I start question?" yet the case is specific and it would be beneficial to hear other experiences even though stackoverflow is focused on more objective info.  
Thanks @HighPerformanceMark yet what I was able to find was patents and some propitiatory software based on water level measurement.

Comment: You can use an approach of type "Content Based Image Retrivial" (CBIR). In your server, you put many image of each gauge, and you use CBIR library to do the request and find which gauge is at work.